# Gensim Contruct the dictionary without loading all texts into memory gensim

Tags: python, bigdata, gensim

Instead of having construct from one single document ('mycorpus.txt'), How can i frame dictionary from multiple documents (Each one going to be 25 MB in file size with 10,000 Files) and please be aware that i am trying "to construct the dictionary without loading all texts into memory" via gensim

```
>>> from gensim import corpora
>>> from six import iteritems
>>> dictionary = corpora.Dictionary(line.lower().split() for line in open('mycorpus.txt'))
>>> stop_ids = [dictionary.token2id[stopword] for stopword in stoplist
>>>             if stopword in dictionary.token2id]
>>> once_ids = [tokenid for tokenid, docfreq in iteritems(dictionary.dfs) if docfreq == 1]
>>> dictionary.filter_tokens(stop_ids + once_ids)  # remove stop words and words that appear only once
>>> dictionary.compactify()  # remove gaps in id sequence after words that were removed
>>> print(dictionary)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need an `iterator` for this.
As taken from [the gensim webiste](https://rare-technologies.com/word2vec-tutorial/#preparing_the_input):

```
class MySentences(object):
    def __init__(self, dirname):
        self.dirname = dirname

    def __iter__(self):
        for fname in os.listdir(self.dirname):
            for line in open(os.path.join(self.dirname, fname)):
                yield line.lower().split()

sentences = MySentences('/some/directory') # a memory-friendly iterator
```

`sentences` is an `iterator` which will open each file **when needed**, use it and then destroy the instance. So at any time, only one file is in memory.

From the website:

> if our input is strewn across several files on disk, with one sentence per line, then instead of loading everything into an in-memory list, we can process the input file by file, line by line

To use it in your case, just replace your `dictionary` line with:

```
dictionary = corpora.Dictionary(line for line in sentences)
```

where `sentences` is the variable we defined earlier which was given the path to the folder with several `.txt` files.

To understand more about Iterators, Iterables and Generators, check out [this blog](https://nvie.com/posts/iterators-vs-generators/).